# How to calculate total standard deviation of sum of multiple groups?

Tags: standard-deviation, clinical-trials

I am writing a review in which I need to find the standard deviation of the sum of multiple subscales within a scale. The mean and standard deviation values of the participants is given seperately under each subscale. Is it possible to calculate the standard deviation of the participants in the total scale?

Example data:

Number of participants = 14

Subscale 1: Mean = -3.14  SD = 14.21

Subscale 2: Mean = 1.79  SD = 8.82

Subscale 3 : Mean = -1.00  SD = 13.06

Total scale : Mean = -3.14 + 1.79 - 1.00 = -2.35

What is the standard deviation in the total scale?

Comment: I don't understand the context of your question and what you mean by scale/subscales but it sounds like you want to use the law of total variance.

Comment: Pretty sure this is already covered by several answers on site. You need their correlations (or their covariances) -- and if your sample calculations are using n-1 divisors, you'll also need the sample sizes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties (where it says "In general, for the sum of $N$ random variables..."), but things alter slightly for finite samples and Bessel-corrected sample calculations.

Comment: How should I calculate the correlations? I do not have access to the raw data.